# Async parsing with AngleSharp

Tags: c#, async-await, console-application, html-parsing, anglesharp

So I want to parse some data from website and I found a tutorial, here is code:

```
public static async void Test()
{
    var config = Configuration.Default.WithDefaultLoader();
    using var context = BrowsingContext.New(config);

    var url = "http://webcode.me";

    using var doc = await context.OpenAsync(url);
    // var title = doc.QuerySelector("title").InnerHtml;
    var title = doc.Title;

    Console.WriteLine(title);

    var pars = doc.QuerySelectorAll("p");

    foreach (var par in pars)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(par.Text().Trim());
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Test();
}
```

And the program quits right after it reaches the:

```
using var doc = await context.OpenAsync(url);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing is waiting for your asynchronous method to complete, so the program quits. You can fix this by amending to use an async main method:

```cs
static Task Main(string[] args)
{
    return Test();
}
```

Or if you're using a version older than C# 7.1 (where async main not supported):

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Test().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

You'll also need to change the return type of `Test` to `async Task`:

```cs
public static async Task Test()
{
    // ...
}
```

You might find the C# 7.1 docs on [async main](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-7.1/async-main) helpful.